# Java code optimalization - Two functions into one

Tags: java, android

Hello I have this code:

```
this.firstBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        final CharSequence[] items = {"1", "2", "3"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SlovnikoidActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("test");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                langFrom.setText(items[item]);
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
});

this.secondBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final CharSequence[] items = {"1", "2", "3"};
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SlovnikoidActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("test");
            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    langFrom.setText(items[item]);
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });
```

There are just two different parts: `this.firstBtn` and `this.secondBtn`
Is there a way how to merge it? For example when I click on `firstBtn` it calls a function `foo(firstBtn)` and `secondBtn` calls `foo(secondBtn)` and the rest would work the same? 
I'm not sure about syntax etc. because I'm new to Java and Android development today.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want can be done relatively easily.  You can define a new class that implements `OnClickListener`, and use a new instance of this class in both locations.

```
class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final CharSequence[] items = {"1", "2", "3"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SlovnikoidActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("test");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                langFrom.setText(items[item]);
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

Your code can then look like this:

```
this.firstBtn.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener());
this.secondBtn.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener());
```

Obviously this solution can be taken further, if your two `MyOnClickListener`'s need to be just slightly different.  This can be done by creating a constructor that takes in the parameters that you want to change and store them as member variables, which are then used on the call to `onClick(...)`:

```
class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    private CharSequence[] items;

    public MyOnClickListener(CharSequence[] _items) {
        items = _items;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SlovnikoidActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("test");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                langFrom.setText(items[item]);
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

And this can then be used like so:

```
final CharSequence[] items1 = {"1", "2", "3"};
final CharSequence[] items2 = {"2", "3", "4"};
this.firstBtn.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(items1));
this.secondBtn.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(items2));
```

***UPDATE***

```
public class SlovnikoidActivity extends Activity {
    //slovnikoidActivity definition

    //inner class definition for MyOnClickListener
    class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
        private CharSequence[] items;

        public MyOnClickListener(CharSequence[] _items) {
            items = _items;
        }

        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SlovnikoidActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("test");
            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    langFrom.setText(items[item]);
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that looks good. I fixed one error by adding `extends SlovnikoidActivity` but there's still one more on 4th line of your code which says `No enclosing instance of the type SlovnikoidActivity is accessible in scope`. I don't know how to fix it because I'm not sure what does it mean. Thanks

Comment: Make this class definition be a subclass of your Activity class (which I think is called `SlovnikoidActivity`).  Doing that will get rid of your exception.

Comment: doing a subclass is made by `extends SlovnikoidActivity`, right? It helps to get rid of some errors but there's still that error `No enclosing instance of the type SlovnikoidActivity is accessible in scope`

Comment: Sorry, I said subclass, but I meant inner class.  I have updated my answer to reflect what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to nicholas.hauschild's answer, if you don't want to make a separate class, just make your activity implement `View.OnClickListener`.

Then, move your `onClick(View v)` method to the same class your button code is already in. If you need to distinguish between different buttons ever, then just do `switch (v.getId())`.

Comment: thanks. I have written `public class SlovnikoidActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener` but there's error `The type SlovnikoidActivity must implement the inherited abstract method View.OnClickListener.onClick(View)`. I tried to change it into `View.OnClickListener.onClick(View)` but there's syntax error and it cannot be resolved